# How to force grid to fit data range

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to remove the extra space between the begin (end) of plot and the begin (end) of data range in matplotlib? I want the grids to be limited to the data range, but I cannot remove these extra spaces. See example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8))
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x), color="black")
ax.yaxis.grid(True, color ="gray", linewidth=0.5)
ax.hlines(y=0.5, color=[66/255, 176/255, 255/255], linestyle='--', xmin=0, xmax=12, linewidth=2)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

I highlight the extra space in red:

[image]

I cannot find a way to fit the grid interval in the data or the blue horizontal line ranges. I tried to reduce the `xmin` argument in the later case but it didn't work. The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.YAxis.grid.html) of `ax.yaxis.grid` shows only 3 arguments for this method (b, which,**kwargsLine2D), none of them looks to be related to the data range.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I put `ax.set_xlim(left=x[0], right=x[-1])` and the regions you highlighted in red disappeared. Is this what you want?

Comment: `ax.margins(x=0)`